# Rythm template reload in prod

Tags: java, template-engine, rythm

We have a requirement to reload templates in the JVM without bouncing it. when we find some modification on the template we wanted to capture the changes , basically we wanted to derive it from last updated date column. Problem is Auto reload feature is disabled in PROD mode.

How to enable reload feature in PROD and what is the impact in performance/memory issue??

**Edited**

Engine.Mode configuration available to change mode but i am concerned to change to dev mode in production.

Answer (score 0):

reload in `PROD` is not supported. You have to run rythm in `DEV` mode, meaning each it the engine will check if the template has changed or not. If it is changed, then rythm will obsolete the current template class loader, create an new class loader and reload all templates.

However only templates that has been changed will be re-parsed and re-compiled.